# White box appears instead of < when editing tags or writing an answer

Tags: bug, android-app

App version: 1.0.26

Device effects: Toshiba AT10 10.1" tablet

Devices not effected: Huawei Ascend G510 phone, Nexus 7 tablet

When you are editing a tag or writing an answer, instead of seeing `<` in the top left corner there is only a white box. This doesn't happen on the ask a question screen (the `X` is in the corner of the screen).

[image]

Comment: ██████████████ +█

Comment: Seems like this was caused by some bad assets, does this still happen for you?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi it is still happening